# multiple methods in dao layer

Tags: java, hibernate, dao

Currently I'm planning to refactor an old codebase which is written in spring+hibernate.

I have seen so many methods in dao layer which is solving same purpose like.

for example I have user_info table

in dao-layer there are so many methods like

```
 getUserInfoById(String userId);
 getUserInfoByName(String name);
 getUserInfoByIdAndName(String userId,String name)
```

and the list goes on.

i know it is very bad practice to follow.

I thought a solution like i will have only one method getUserInfo(User user)
inside this method i will encapsulate query construction like

`query.with(user.username).with(user.userId)` ...

i don't know is it correct solution to follow...

any suggestions? Any links to pages that explain this concept from the very basic stuff is also appreciated.

Comment: whey not use `Criteria` then?

Comment: yup currently i'm constructing my query with Criteria object. thanks a lot for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after an intense browsing i found spring-jpa integration [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/)

only thing i have created is interface per entity. spring itself handles creation of DAO layer and handles all the operation's on that entity and also support bulk operation's.we can add our custom method's inside that interface spring jpa will implement those methods.no need to write any code which are related to DAO layer.

sample example:

@Repository

```
public interface UserRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<UserCore, Serializable>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<UserCore>  {

}
```

we can also return java stream from DAO methods as  explained [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/)

it also have specification support which is similar to criteria in hibernate.

Comment: But won't this still leave you with a lot of methods doing similar things? The API of your dao-layer will still have a lot of methods doing almost the same thing

Comment: nope, i have replaced all the methods with one search method which takes JPA specification. you can add any criteria to that specification.